# send string variable from raspberry pi 2 to android app over bluetooth

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I am developing an android app using android studio to receive string(results) from raspberry pi after image processing code .

I am using python 2.7.3, opencv 3.1, numpy 1.8.
bluetooth chip RN42XVP connected to the raspberry pi 2

I read this question
[Receiving data from raspberry pi in android via bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837785/receiving-data-from-raspberry-pi-in-android-via-bluetooth)

I tried it but it gave too many errors and undefined variable!
anyway I think it is not specifically what am searching for.

what i need is simply to send the content of string from a python code on raspberry pi to android application.

when a button clicked in android app it will receive and display the content

Comment: How is the device connected? Is it integrated in the Raspberry Pi? Is it external and communicates serially (UART, I2C, ...)?

Comment: external bluetooth chip of type RN42XVP

Comment: That I understood, but how how is it connected to your Raspberry Pi? Without that I can't help you.

Comment: i connected bluetooth chip to raspberry pi using wires. I did not write any code related to sending the string from python code to android app because I don't know what to write. did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the general approach: read the manual

1. Read the data sheet, it has all the information on how to connect and talk to the device. You need to figure out the following:

   - How do you want to connect to the device (the product page mentions UART or USB).
   - depending on your choice you figure out what hardware this module needs in order to run (Capacitors, Voltage supply, etc.).
2. After that you connect the device to USB- or UART-capable pins on your Raspberry Pi.
3. Then you want to open a device file descriptor on you raspberry pi, which talks to those pins. (Normally a `open(file, "w")` should be sufficient). (If you are not sure, refer to the Raspberry Pi documentation or google it.)
4. Everything you write into this file descriptor gets sent to the wireless module.
5. Figure out how to communicate with the module (what commands you need to send, how to set it up, etc.).
6. Write your python code.

After Googling it, it seems, that this is a very popular module and has already been used with Arduinos, maybe you can find a tutorial on how to connect it, I'm pretty sure that there also are some libraries already written, which spares you the hassle of writing everything yourself.

The following link describes how to connect the module with an Arduino, but it should be easy to do the same with your Raspberry Pi: http://dduino.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/arduino-rn-42-bluetooth-module.html

Comment: I could not find the code in link that you sent, only the connection

Comment: Yes, this link only includes the pin out. Either google for a library or write one from scratch using the data sheet (Maybe a vendor even supplies a library, or example code). I am sure, that you wont come around writing some code of your own regarding the Bluetooth module.